# How to generate *.eml file with Swift Mailer (in Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, eml

I want to create an *.eml file, which I want to use as a template for Outlook. My project is using Laravel.

I’m aware of the SwiftMailer function toString(), which is used to convert the message into MIME-format. See below for my approach. That code generates the header properly, but body and and html-template(blade), which I pass to the method, won’t be displayed the way I want to...

The Mail mustn't be send, but generated.

I didn’t find any related problems on the Internet. Saving generated *.eml files doesn’t seem to be popular :)
Does anyone can think of a solution?

```
public function generateEmlFile(Request $request) {
    //...

    $data = array('name' => "recipient");

    Mail::send('emails.ordering', $data, function($message) {
        $message->from('example@mail.com');
        $message->to('example@mail.com');
        $message->subject('Subject');

        $content = $message->toString();
        dd($content);
    });

    return true;
}
```

a dump of the work so far:

```
Message-ID: <4900a58cfb9b22900d8500b6e80f3022@examlpe-domain>\r\n
Date: Wed, 17 Jul 2019 15:51:38 +0200\r\n
Subject: Subject\r\n
From: example@mail.com\r\n
Reply-To: example-project <example-project@examlpe-domain.com>\r\n
To: example@mail.com\r\n
MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not to use any external Swiftmailer transport extension or do any custom coding in EventServiceProvider. The following solution is much simpler:

Create logdir `logs/emails`

Add an extra channel configuration to `config/logging.php`:

```php
    'channels' => [

        // ...

        'emails' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/emails/' . \Illuminate\Support\Str::uuid() . '.eml'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
```

And then simply use the following in your `.env`:

```sh
MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL=emails
```

That way, you get wonderful `logs/emails/<UUID>.eml` files with only one drawback (that does no harm): The first line (before `Message-ID: ...`) of the email header is prefixed with log formatting prefix `[_TIMESTAMP_] local.DEBUG:` . As a non-standard email header is ignored by all/most email clients, this should be no issue in development.

Comment: A small update on this...

This solution has multiple drawbacks! The best solution is to use a `LogSentMessage` event listener and listen to the `MessageSent` event, as @davewood has presented here. So, please downvote my post and upvote his!

I have written a full blog post about this topic: **[Log emails as *.eml in Laravel Mailer](https://pipo.blog/articles/20211203-laravel-mailer-log-eml)**

Answer (score 1):

you can listen to the LogSentMessage event

```
diff --git a/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php b/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
index 723a290..f7568ec 100644
--- a/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
+++ b/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
@@ -18,6 +18,9 @@ class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
         Registered::class => [
             SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
         ],
+       'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
+           'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
+       ],
     ];
```

after adding these 3 lines run `php artisan event:generate`

this should create the file `app/Listeners/LogSentMessage.php`

inside the handle function you can access the complete msg -> `$event->message->toString();`

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#events

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sending the email in the application, there's no need to use the laravel `Mail` facade.

There is a extension for Swiftmailer that supports saving emails as `.eml` files
https://github.com/geekdevs/swift-mailer-extensions